# Showing more details on visual studio uml

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml, field

I have started using the visual studio uml feature. I would like to export the umls to a document I'm doing.

The problem is the umls generated by the visual studio are not showing the type of the fields or what are returning the methods.

Now it is being shown:

```
Fields:
_a;

Methods:
Execute
```

And I would like:

```
Fields:
bool _a;

Methods:
void Execute(): void;
```

Is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have figured out how to do it. You just have to go Class Diagram > Change Member format.